# Select an id from a group sql which returns duplicate records?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to select `CompanyId` column only from the following SQL;

```
select CompanyId,
           row_number() over (partition by [GradeName] order by [TankNumber] ) rn
    from [Data_DB].[dbo].[Company]  where CompanyCode='ASAAA'
```

In the SQL, I try to figure out duplicate records, and from another table i want to delete some records based on the `CompanyId` from above query.

that is;

```
delete from [[dbo].ObservationData 
where CompanyId in (select CompanyId,
               row_number() over (partition by [GradeName] order by [TankNumber] ) rn
        from [Data_DB].[dbo].[Company]  where CompanyCode='ASAAA')
```

How can I modify above query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delete from [[dbo].ObservationData 
where CompanyId in (select CompanyId from (select CompanyId,
               row_number() over (partition by [GradeName] order by [TankNumber] ) rn
        from [Datat_DB].[dbo].[Company]  where CompanyCode='ASAAA') a where rn > 1 ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't care which duplicate gets retained or deleted, you may try using a deletable CTE here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [GradeName] ORDER BY [TankNumber]) rn
    FROM [Data_DB].[dbo].[Company]
    WHERE CompanyCode = 'ASAAA'
)

DELETE
FROM cte
WHERE rn > 1;
```

This answer arbitrarily retains the "first" duplicate, with first being defined as the record with the earliest row number.